# How to show shopping cart icon always right side in menu using boostrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

I tried to show shopping cart icon always in right side for mobile,tab,desktop using boostrap but it is not working for responsive.How can i show shopping cart icon always right side.

```
    <div class="shopingicons mr-auto">

        <a href="cart.html" class="icons-btn d-inline-block bag">
          <span class="icon-shopping-bag"></span>
          <span class="number">2</span>
        </a>

      </div>
```

Demo:https://jsfiddle.net/nvk87are/9/

Answer (score 0):

Add your following code after `</ul>` tag in the navbar code. I tried it in your code and it worked.

```html
<div style="float:right">
  <div class="shopingicons mr-auto">           
    <a href="cart.html" class="icons-btn d-inline-block bag">
      <span class="icon-shopping-bag"></span>
      <span class="number">2</span>
    </a>
            
          </div>
        </div>
```

Want more help? Reply and ask again

Answer (score 0):

Your `navbarResponsive` is hidden in responsive mode and in larger view it's showing up and taking the place of your cart icons.

You can swap the position of your `#navbarResponsive` and the `.shoppingicons`. [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/qgrxb5)

Here you can check the [working-demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hy8w6ef3/)

Comment: in mobile,ipad not wrking..shopping icon going down

Comment: @NilaVaani you can use this css to solve that `.navbar-expand-lg .container {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}`

Comment: Sure, please check this [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/49qkh6jw/). Here i've used css positioning to fix that.